# The class is not public in the cmd windows

Tags: java

The main function code is here,

```
public class AppGraphInout{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AppFrame();
}
```

It is right in the IDE (IntelliJ). But if I want to run it by cmd window, it would say, graphic.java:6:error, you need to declare public class AppGraphInout.

What is the difference between IDE and cmd windows?

Comment: `graphic.java` is not `AppGraphInout.java` (and `AppGraphInout` must be in `AppGraphInout.java`).

Comment: @Zishuo Yang What is the `.java` filename of your class `AppGraphInout`?

Comment: @user3437460 thx. I have corrected the filename

Comment: @ZishuoYang So it is working now?